# How can I filter out profanity in numeric IDs?

Tags: numeric, profanity

I want to use numeric IDs in a web application I am developing... However, as the ID is visible to users as a URL, I want to filter out profanity. Things like (I'll leave it to you to figure out what they are):

```
page.php?id=455
page.php?id=8008135
page.php?id=69
```

Has anyone solved this? Is this even a real problem?

Does it make sense just to skip numbers in my database sequence?

See also: [*How can I filter out profanity in base36 IDs?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032310/how-can-i-filter-out-profanity-in-base36-ids).

Comment: you actually made me to google for 8008135. And who would think... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about you using GUIDs? That would encode the actual numbers.  I would bet most users don't even notice what is on the url.